# Display Vimeo's control bar using WebView and Android 6

Tags: android, webview, vimeo

I was wondering if there is any problem with the Vimeo API when we try to show a video on an Android 6 device.

I use [Vimeo's embedded code for the Universal Player as suggested.](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding) 
The video is working as expected on any previous Android versions, but on 6 the control bar is [not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAKe3.png)

The `WebView`'s settings on my code are

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

And I load the `WebView` like that:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://vimeo.com", htmlForVideoId(videoId),
    "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Furthermore, I set a `new WebViewClient()` and a `new WebChromeClient()`

Comment: If you try loading a Web page through `loadUrl()` that has the Vimeo embed in it, does it work? Perhaps the problem is with `htmlForVideoId()`, or with using `loadDataWithBaseURL()`. If even a regular Web page with the Vimeo embed doesn't work, though, then the problems are most likely tied to WebView. I have never used the Vimeo stuff, so I don't have any specific suggestions regarding their code.

Comment: Hi Mark,
the loadUrl() or loadData()  will not work , and the htmlForVideoId() method is just  Vimeo's embedded code for the Universal Player.

Comment: Does Vimeo have a sample Android app that uses this Universal Player in a `WebView`? If so, does it work?

Comment: Unfortunately, Vimeo does not have any sample Android app. According to the staff members of Vimeo there are 2 ways to display a video on Android: 
1)Embed the video, and only the video, on a page you control, and then embed that page in an iframe in your app. and 
2) Use the third-party/external player URLs they provide, and use those URLs with the Android media player. 
I use the first option since I would like to show the video within the app.